# Shift an element to the end of array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which contains list of pagrank values. Consider below array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagerank] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagerank] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagerank] => R
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagerank] => 2
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagerank] => 7
        )

)
```

I want to shift/move page rank with 'R' like:

```
[2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pagerank] => R
        )
```

to the end of array and it should be on last index of array?

Edit: The array key is unknown.

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359652/how-do-i-move-an-array-element-with-a-known-key-to-the-end-of-an-array-in-php

Comment: You can use `array_slice`

Comment: and how many R will be there ? only one ?

Comment: @PrasanthBendra, Only one R will be there.

Comment: You should update your question to clarify that you don't know the array key.

Comment: @IrfanDayan So, am I safe to assume, that this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2359699/1167953 ( the uksort part) didn't do any good for you? Because if yes, then please explain why. Otherwise, why didn't you read the whole thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the index is unknown:

```
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if($val->pagerank == 'R') {
        $item = $array[$key];
        unset($array[$key]);
        array_push($array, $item); 
        break;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to modify the array while it is being iterated over just find the index then make the modifications.

```
$foundIndex = false;
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if($val->pagerank == 'R') {
        $foundIndex = $key;
        break;
    }
}
if($foundIndex !== false) {
    $item = $array[$foundIndex];
    unset($array[$foundIndex]);
    array_push($array, $item);
}
```

Comment: FYI, its a bad practice to change the array that is iterated. =)

Comment: @liding But the `break;` stops the iteration so the array isn't used after it has been changed.

Comment: Although this modification of the array while it is being iterated is safe, I think @liding makes a good point given that most people might think that it's safe to modify arrays this way.

Answer (score 4):

```
$item = $array[2];
unset($array[2]);
array_push($array, $item);
```

Comment: The index for value 'R' is not knowable. When I output my array it can be on any index like it can be on [5] or [11]. The only thing i know is the value 'R' and I want to shift that element to the end of array

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$var = array(
    'name' => 'thename',
    'title' => 'thetitle',
    'media' => 'themedia'
);

// Remove first element (the name)
$name = array_shift($var);
// Add it on to the end
$var['name'] = $name;

var_dump($var);

/*
array(3) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(8) "thetitle"
  ["media"]=>
  string(8) "themedia"
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "thename"
}
*/
```

Ref: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/177878-move-array-index-to-end/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $item=null;
    foreach ($array['pagerank'] as $key => $value) 
    {
     if( $value=="R")
     {
     $item = $array[$key];
     unset($array[$key]);
     break;
     }
    }
     if($item !=null)
     array_push($array, $item);
```

Comment: `$value` would be an object it would never be equal to 'R'

Comment: @Irfan Dayan  thats ok check corrected answer use $array['pagerank'] instead of $array

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one object with a 'R' value:

```
$current_array = $sorted_array = Array(
    ...
);
foreach($current_array as $current_key => $element){
    if($element->pagerank == 'R'){
        unset($sorted_array[$current_key]);
        $sorted_array[] = $element;
    }
}
unset($current_array);
```

Comment: FYI, in OP it is an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place R as the last value and keeping your keys, you could do this:

```
$arr = array(
    (object)array('pagerank' => 1),
    (object)array('pagerank' => 'R'),
    (object)array('pagerank' => 2),
);

// Store in temp var.
$tmp_arr = $arr;

// Sort temp array to put 'R' in top.
asort($tmp_arr);

// Reset to be able to find the first key in the sorted array.
reset($tmp_arr);

// Get key from first value in array.
$key = key($tmp_arr);

// Store value from first key.
$item = $tmp_arr[$key];

// Unset key from original array.
unset($arr[$key]);

// Insert as last value in original array using original key.
$arr[$key] = $item;

// Print result.
var_dump($arr);
```

This will give you:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["pagerank"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
    ["pagerank"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["pagerank"]=>
    string(1) "R"
  }
}
```

See: http://codepad.org/gPhrktuJ

Comment: If you do not want to keep all the original keys, that would work as well. In my example the keys in the array are kept. By using array_push you lose the key from the object with the value 'R'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arr  = array(array("pagerank" => 3),
              array("pagerank" => 1),
              array("pagerank" => 'R'),
              array("pagerank" => 4),
              array("pagerank" => 7),
              array("pagerank" => 5),
              array("pagerank" => 2)
        );

foreach($arr as $key=>$ar){
   if($ar["pagerank"] == "R"){
     $unset  = $key;
     break;
   }
}

$val    = $arr[$unset];
unset($arr[$unset]);
$arr[]  = $val; 

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: FYI, in OP it is an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is specifically the value of r, you can use `array_search`

`array_search` returns the key if an item exists in the array, otherwise returns false.

```
$needle = "R";
if($key = array_search($needle, $pageRankArray)) {
   unset($pageRankArray[$key]); // Delete an item from the array
   array_push($pageRankArray, $needle); // inserts element at the end of the array
}
```

Comment: They are objects in an array not values.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value){
    if ($value->pagerank == 'R'){
        $arr[] = $value;
        unset($arr[$key]);
        break;
    }
}
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use array_filter.

Taking $arr as input array:

```
$arr=Array
(
    (Object) ['pagerank' => 3],
    (Object) ['pagerank' => 1],
    (Object) ['pagerank' => "R"],
    (Object) ['pagerank' => 2],
    (Object) ['pagerank' => 7],
);
$result=array_filter($arr,function($item){return $item->pagerank!="R";})+$arr;
var_dump($arr,$result);
```

The result will be:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'pagerank' => int 3
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'pagerank' => int 1
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'pagerank' => string 'R' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'pagerank' => int 2
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'pagerank' => int 7

array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'pagerank' => int 3
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'pagerank' => int 1
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'pagerank' => int 2
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[5]
      public 'pagerank' => int 7
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'pagerank' => string 'R' (length=1)
```