# Foreach iteration position

Tags: php, loops, foreach, iteration

Is there a way in PHP to move certain iteration to a certain position in the loop?

For example I have an array:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

We have an array of 1 to 9 but I want 5 to be placed at the end of the iteration so the outcome would look like this:

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
5
```

Comment: Can you clarify 1. Does the array always contain 9 values? 2. Are you always moving the 5th value to the end? There are loads of options, but it depends what your actual requirement is...

Comment: add it to a separate array, then add it to the end of the array `for($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) { if($i == 5) { $arr2[] = $i; } else { $arr1[] = $i; }` etc

Comment: The array is variable but there's always number 5 in the array.

Comment: Maybe this question will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359652/how-do-i-move-an-array-element-with-a-known-key-to-the-end-of-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you are asking. Anyway you can obtain the required output using `unset` and `[] operator`

```
$element = $array[4];
unset($array[4]);
$array[] = $element;
```

Live: http://codepad.org/cWZHjJwy

If you need to search only for 5 then just get the key with `array_search()`:

```
$key = array_search(5,$array);
unset($array[$key]);
$array[] = 5;
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know you could use unset. It's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This below code will find the position of the number 5, remove it and add it to the end of the array. Finally we iterate over values.

```
$numbers = range(1, 9);

// find the position of value 5
$position = array_search(5, $numbers);

// save the value and remove from array
$value = $numbers[$position];
unset($numbers[$position]);

// add it back at the end
$numbers[] = $value;

// print the values
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number . ' ';
}
```

### Result

1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 5